# How to find entry of each a(i, j) in n*n matrix where n<=900 and a(i,j)=0 or a(i, j)=1?

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose i have given n basically `n*n` matrix with all zero's at start.

And sum's associated with each row and column is given.

eg. `n=4`

Matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

given rows sum : `2, 2, 1, 1`

given columns sum:  `2, 0, 2, 2`

So output matrix should look like:

```
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
```

There's always a solution exist. 
So for `n=4`, `0<=rowsum<=4 and 0<=columnsum<=4`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would be a shame for such a nice question to be closed for lack of effort.

Comment: Should the output matrix be that solution specifically? There are more solutions, for example 1010 0011 0001 1000

Comment: @harold any solution should be fine as long as it matches given inputs

Comment: @NitinSinghal please explain your question little more.

Comment: Is it always possible?

Comment: @Daniel yes.There's always a solution exist

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this with a greedy approach.

```
while not filled:
    find biggest unfilled row:
        fill in putting 1s in columns with largest sums
```

In your case you started with:

```
    2 2 0 2
  ----------
2 | _ _ _ _
2 | _ _ _ _
1 | _ _ _ _
1 | _ _ _ _
```

Filling in one of the rows we get:

```
    1 1 0 2
  ----------
2 | _ _ _ _
  | 1 1 0 0
1 | _ _ _ _
1 | _ _ _ _
```

Fill in another:

```
      1   1
  ----------
  | 1 0 0 1
  | 1 1 0 0
1 | _ _ _ _
1 | _ _ _ _
```

And the other two can be filled in similarly:

```
  ----------
  | 1 0 0 1
  | 1 1 0 0
  | 0 1 0 0
  | 0 0 0 1
```

Assuming that the sum of the row values matches the sum of the column values, and `0 <= value <= n` for all of them, this procedure will always work.

---

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, it is possible for no solution to exist in other ways.  That will be detectable by the fact that you try to fill in a row and there aren't enough columns left to fill it with.

However if you run into such a barrier, then there was no solution.

Comment: ... or the opposite approach, using min sums and zeros

Comment: The last sentence might need the additional assumption "[...] and that there always exists at least one solution, [...]", since for instance "02" times "02" is not solvable.

Comment: That's an algorithm which should work well I think, in cubic time. Can't help but wonder if it can be done in quadratic.

Comment: ... unless the answer is amended to say that the approach in this answer can also be used to determine whether a solution exists or not, in which case my former comment is irrelevant as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MelvinWM Good point!  If this fails, then there is no solution.  But you thought of a way that there could be no solution that I had missed.

Comment: Can you explain why this always returns a solution, if one exists?

Answer (score 0):

Btilly's answer will work for you. However it can be improved. Instead of finding the largest-sum row and column each time, you can pre-process by sorting them in descending order, but it's important to keep their original positions stored. You can use a simple class:

```java
class SortedRow {
    int val;
    int originalIndex;
    public SortedRow(val, originalIndex) {
        this.val = val;
        this.originalIndex = originalIndex;
    }
}
```

Then sort them (rowVals and colVals are the arrays with desired sums):

```java
public static void preprocess(int[] rowVals, int[] colVals){
    SortedRow[] rows = new SortedRow[n];
    SortedRow[] cols = new SortedRow[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rows[i] = new SortedRow(rowVals[i], i);
        cols[i] = new SortedRow(colVals[i], i);
    }
    // Sort both arrays by val with some sorting algorithm of your choice - in descending order!
}
```

Now you can start filling a nxn matrix in a greedy approach like Btilly suggested, except you don't have to look for the largest one each time around - you already have it. Fill it out by the `originalIndex` field of the new class.

It improves worst-case runtime from cubic into quadratic: Preprocess runs in O(nlogn), could even be linear if you have some prior knowledge on the value of `n`. Filling out the matrix runs in O(n^2).